# How we can calculate the free warranty time for a software application

Tags: planning, scheduling, resource-planning, deliverables, fixed-price

I am a freelancer, and I am going to build a software application developed using SharePoint Online as the DataSource, Power Apps and Power Automate. The Project mainly includes automating 14 business processes which have multiple approval steps, building 4 dashboards and building 4 integrations with other 3rd party systems.

The project is expected to take 650 hours of total 18 weeks. Now I am not sure about the free warranty period I need to provide? I mentioned to the client that I will provide 60-days free warranty which include fixing any bugs raised after delivering the system. but the client mentioned that they need 12-months free warranty. I mentioned to them that 12-months free warranty will be too much for a 4.5-months project. So I am not sure if there are any standards for calculating the free warranty for such a software application?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3 months of warranty is good. You can offer a 1-year maintenance contract that starts after the warranty. It is generally priced as 1% of the project quote per month which shouldn't be less than your daily rate.

Comment: thanks for the helpful reply. i am offering 60-days free warranty which is around 2-months. so generally speaking, how the free warranty duration can be calculated based on the overall project duration, is there such a formula?

Comment: I don't think there should be a dynamically calculated warranty period. But, if the customer asks for, let's say 1 year of warranty, I include 9 months of maintenance budget into the project budget.

Comment: i am asking mainly on the period for free warranty which should cover defects and bugs not adding new features or doing any kind of additional work

Comment: Yeah, I got that. What I wanted to tell you was, the customer can ask for a warranty of 12 months. If you think that the warranty should be 3 months at most, then you can add the cost of 9 months of maintenance to your project budget and the customer will think that they get 12 months of warranty, but you give 3 months of warranty and 9 months of paid maintenance.

PS: Maintenance --> Paid guarantee / Support --> Paid new features

Answer (score 1):

You basically need to have a good estimate on the expected actual work required during the warranty period. This depends very much on what kind of fixes are covered by the warranty. If you have very clearly specified requirements where deviations can be objectively measured, you're in a far better position than when your customer expects to get all features they didn't initially think of implemented for free "under warranty".

The calculation for this involves your experience and gut feeling about your customer, which nobody here can guess.

In any case, if you have a decent estimate of the work expected under warranty, you add that to the project price. There isn't such a thing as free warranty, it's just an insurance covering the risk of additional repair work, and its premium is included in the project costs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i am asking mainly about the period for free warranty which should ONLY covers fixing defects and bugs not adding new features or doing any kind of additional work

Comment: Yes that's clear - the question is if it's clear to the customer as well? :-) For standard free warranty, the estimation method given by @Nezih-TINAS looks very plausible.